# PHPMail not formating mail to html

Tags: php, html, email, outlook, phpmailer

Can anybody tell me why when i try to send an html mail from a php script. My outlook receives it in the same way as I see it in my db?

currently my tool sends an email with the `$body` var as `<p>Dear client,</p> <p>&nbsp;</p> <p>Please find your account statement attached.</p> <p>&nbsp;</p> <p>Kind Regards</p>`

with the code:

```
$email = new PHPMailer();
        $email->From      = $from_email_address;
        $email->FromName  = $from_name;
        $email->Subject   = $subject;
        $email->IsHTML(true); 
        $email->Body      = $body;
        $email->AddAddress($client_email);

        $email->AddAttachment(ROOTDIR.'/reports/statement.pdf', "Statement.pdf");

        echo $email->Send();
```

But when outlook receives the email it is not formatted like the html code requires. Outlook merely shows the `<p>`tags as is in the original code.

**P.S:**

I noticed if I add this line: `$body='<p>Dear client,</p><p>Please find this email well</p>';` the email is generated in html and shows properly. But when it loads this value from the database `<p>Dear client,</p> <p>&nbsp;</p> <p>Please find your account statement attached for your company.</p> <p>&nbsp;</p> <p>Kind Regards</p>` it sends the code as text. Does not convert it to html.

What would be causing this?

Comment: I expect there is an extra level of encoding being applied in your db layer. Viewing the value of $body in a browser may be hiding the additional encoding- view it from a command line.

Answer (score 0):

Add email header for HTML Content

```
$email = new PHPMailer();

$email->headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$email->headers.= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=us-ascii' . "\r\n";

        $email->From      = $from_email_address;
        $email->FromName  = $from_name;
        $email->Subject   = $subject;
        $email->IsHTML(true); 
        $email->Body      = $body;
        $email->AddAddress($client_email);

        $email->AddAttachment(ROOTDIR.'/reports/statement.pdf', "Statement.pdf");

        echo $email->Send();
```